# How can I limit the number of characters for a console input? C#

Tags: c#, console-application, user-input

Basically I want 200 characters maximum to come up in Console.ReadLine() for user input before characters start being suppressed. I want it like TextBox.MaxLength except for console input. How would I go about this?

And I don't want to do `input.Substring(0, 200).`

**Solved:**

I used my own ReadLine function which was a loop of Console.ReadKey().

It looks like this, essentially:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
bool loop = true;
while (loop)
{
    ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true); // won't show up in console
    switch (keyInfo.Key)
    {
         case ConsoleKey.Enter:
         {
              loop = false;
              break;
         }
         default:
         {
              if (sb.Length < 200)
              {
                  sb.Append(keyInfo.KeyChar);
                  Console.Write(keyInfo.KeyChar);
              }
              break;
         }
    }
}

return sb.ToString();
```

Thanks everyone

Comment: what is the overall scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use `Console.Read()`, you can loop through until you reach the 200 characters or until an enter key is entered.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int i, count = 0;

while ((i = Console.Read()) != 13)   // 13 = enter key (or other breaking condition)
{
    if (++count > 200)  break;
    sb.Append ((char)i);
}
```

**EDIT**

Turns out that `Console.ReadKey()` is preferred to `Console.Read()`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85.aspx

Answer (score 8):

There is no way to limit the text entered into ReadLine. As the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline.aspx) explains,

> A line is defined as a sequence of
>   characters followed by a carriage
>   return (hexadecimal 0x000d), a line
>   feed (hexadecimal 0x000a), or the
>   value of the `Environment.NewLine`

What you can do, is use ReadKey in a loop that does not allow going over 200, and breaks if the user keys `Environment.NewLine`.