# Char tryParse not working as I thought?

Tags: c#

I have some problem with a method that I have done in c#. I'm trying to stop user from entering anything else then y and n. It's almost working that I want, but user can still enter more than one sign, and then it doesn't work! How can I do to also check if char is more than one char? I thought the tryParse solved that? Thanks!

```
// Method to check if item is food or not
    private void ReadIfFoodItem()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter if food item or not (y/n): ");

        if (char.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out responseFoodItem))
        {
            if(Char.IsNumber(responseFoodItem))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(errorMessage);
                ReadIfFoodItem();
            }
            else
            {
                // Set true or false to variable depending on the response
                if ((responseFoodItem == 'y' || responseFoodItem == 'Y'))
                {
                    foodItem = true;
                    selectedVATRate = 12; // Extra variable to store type of VAT
                }
                else if ((responseFoodItem == 'n' || responseFoodItem == 'N'))
                {
                    foodItem = false;
                    selectedVATRate = 25; // Extra variable to store type of VAT
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(errorMessage);
                    ReadIfFoodItem();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You sure are hoping for a lot!

Comment: If you want to limit the user to entering 1 character, can't you just use `Console.Read()`?

Comment: Perhaps I should add that I'm new to C# and this solution isn't the best! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code "works" in that it produces the expected results.

```
        char responseFoodItem;

        Console.Write("Enter if food item or not (y/n): ");

        if (char.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out responseFoodItem))
        {
            // Set true or false to variable depending on the response
            if ((responseFoodItem == 'y' || responseFoodItem == 'Y'))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("foodItem = true");
            }
            else if ((responseFoodItem == 'n' || responseFoodItem == 'N'))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("foodItem = false");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unrecognised input");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input");
        }
```

However, has others have pointed out using `ReadKey` is a better solution if you want to limit the input to a single key. It also means that the user doesn't have to press the Return/Enter key for the input to be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

`char` represents a single character, so `How can I do to also check if char is more than one char? I thought the tryParse solved that?` seems a bit nonsensical... `TryParse` will try and parse a single character from your input and will explicitly fail if the value is `null` or has a length > 1.

Instead of checking a character, just check the string, e.g.:

```
string line = Console.ReadLine();
switch (line.ToUpperInvariant())
{
    case "Y":
        // Do work for y/Y
       break;
    case "N":
        // Do work for n/N
        break;
    default:
        // Show error.
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`char.TryParse` simply tries to parse the string supplied as an argument, it does not limit the number of characters that you can input to the console using `Console.ReadLine`.

When the user inputs more than a single character, `char.TryParse` will fail because the string returned by `Console.ReadLine` doesn't contain a single character.

You should use `Console.Read` instead.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying all kind of combination to use Console.Read, but I always get en ren underline? What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I do to also check if char is more than one char?

```
string line = Console.ReadLIne();
If(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line) && line.Length > 1)
```

for reading a *single* char use `Console.ReadChar()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Console.ReadLine allows users to type a string of any length and press enter.

> How can I do to also check if char is more than one char? I thought the tryParse solved that?

From [the manual page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.tryparse.aspx):

> Converts the value of the specified string to its equivalent Unicode character. A return code indicates whether the conversion succeeded or failed....The conversion fails if the s parameter is null **or the length of s is not 1.**

Have you tried using Console.ReadKey instead of ReadLine?

Answer (score 0):

To check it the user has inserted more then one char you could check the string length instead of use Char.TryParse

```
......
private void ReadIfFoodItem()
{
 string answer=string.empty;
 Console.Write("Enter if food item or not (y/n): ");
 answer=Console.ReadLine()
 if (answer.lenght>=1))
    {
           //error
          .......
    }
```

...............

Answer (score 0):

Use Console.ReadKey() to limit the amount of characters. To test whether you have a Y or an N then you can compare the ASCII codes or use a regular expression.

Comment: When I just use Console.Read() I get a red line under the code!?

Comment: Sorry was meant to be ReadKey

Answer (score 0):

This answer should help you: [How can I limit the number of characters for a console input? C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544467/how-can-i-limit-the-number-of-characters-for-a-console-input-c-sharp)

The console does not limit the user input (well it does, but to 256 characters), nor does `char.TryParse` which doesn't do anything at all to limit the input length.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Console.ReadKey
It's just one keystroke for the user and you know there won't be more than one char.

Answer (score 0):

Why not comparing to the input'ed string?
And why not simplifying the comparison?

```
using System.Linq;

private static string[] ValidAnswers = new string[]{ "y", "yes" };

// Method to check if item is food or not
private void ReadIfFoodItem() {
    Console.Write("Enter if food item or not (y/n): ");
    string ans = Console.ReadLine();
    // Checks if the answer matches any of the valid ones, ignoring case.
    if (PositiveAnswers.Any(a => string.Compare(a, ans, true) == 0)) {
        foodItem = true;
        selectedVATRate = 12; // Extra variable to store type of VAT
    } else {
        foodItem = false;
        selectedVATRate = 25; // Extra variable to store type of VAT
    }
}
```

Alternatively, as others said, you can use [Console.ReadKey()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readkey.aspx).