# How do I force user to not be able to type past a certain point?

Tags: c#, keyboard, character, console-application, limit

I am currently making a maze program where the user types which direction they would like to go, but they can type anything thanks to the `Console.Read()` method. Is there any way to limit how many characters a user can type in a given space?

Answer (score 0):

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544467/how-can-i-limit-the-number-of-characters-for-a-console-input-c-sharp)

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int i, count = 0;

while ((i = Console.Read()) != 13)   // 13 = enter key (or other breaking condition)
{
    if (++count > 200)  break;
    sb.Append ((char)i);
}
```

Hope it helps, you can change the limit to the number you want.

You can also set a timer, and when the time its been running is more than a minute, then `break`.

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of an ActionListener

Comment: You should include the relevant information from the link in your answer with reference. The answer as it stands would be worthless if the page was ever removed.

Comment: Please consider expanding your answer. Link-only answers with little to no explanation are generally not considered to be answers as *you* haven't really answered their question, you've simply redirected their inquiry. If you don't feel like doing so, simply add it as a comment instead.

Comment: I would add the comment if I have the reputation to do it, but since I dont, I cant leave it sorry

Comment: would anyone else offer another answer preferably relavent to an action listener