# VB.NET Console.ReadLine() min length?

Tags: vb.net, console-application, console.readline

How would you be able to read less than the standard 254 characters from the console, in VB.NET with `Console.ReadLine()`?

I have tried using `Console.ReadKey()`:

```
Dim A As String = ""

Dim B As Char

For i = 0 To 10

    B = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar
    A = A & B

Next

MsgBox(A)
```

It limits me and it returns the string, but how could it work if a user was to enter less than 10 characters?

Comment: What are you trying to do? There's Console.ReadKey() to read one character.

Comment: I'm trying to use console.readline() as I want to read about 20 characters but I don't want the user entering more than this. So is there a way to limit the number of characters someone can enter on a console?

Comment: You could inform them not to enter more than twenty characters, then if they do throw out their input and output "Please do not enter more than 20 characters." and have them do it again. Other than that, I'm not sure there's a built-in way to do this.

Comment: Are you using VB.NET? There is no Console in VBA.

Comment: Oops sorry yes i'm using vb.net, and I know you could error trap it using .length etc. But I was wondering if you could limit them in the actual console.

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544467/how-can-i-limit-the-number-of-characters-for-a-console-input-c-sharp

Comment: Yes basically that, I want to limit the number of characters the user can enter when i use console.readline() so it's below the normal 254 characters.

Comment: try the solutions there

Comment: I will try them, but they are in C# an my program is in VB.NET.

Comment: I think you can probably manage to write a loop in VB.Net. :) The point is that you can use Console.ReadKey() to only allow the user to enter however many characters you want. You use ReadKey() for every character and each time it runs, increment a counter. When the counter is too high stop writing the character to the console and stop appending it to the string.

Comment: Ok I see, I will quickly write some code for that and see if it works, thanks.

Comment: I have updated my findings in the main question

Comment: For your update, try `Dim B As Char` and `B = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked, now the only thing is how would it work if the user was to enter a string which I didn't know the length of but It has to be under a certain number of characters. Instead of having to always input 10 characters.

Comment: This is getting to be too much for comments, and really is identical to the question @Savanna referenced, which also shows how to break out of the loop when enter is pressed.  I'll throw out an answer anyway!

Comment: Currently working on a loop, if you would be able to do what @savanna said then that would be great. But its quite hard for me as i'm not an expert programer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To limit the input to 10 characters, while allowing for less that 10 characters to be entered by pressing the Enter key, you can use a loop like this.  It checks for the enter key and exits the loop if it's pressed, or the loop will naturally end once 10 characters have been entered.

**EDIT - updated per comments**

```
Imports System.Text

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim userInput = New StringBuilder()
        Dim maxLength = 10
        While True
            ' Read, but don't output character
            Dim cki As ConsoleKeyInfo = Console.ReadKey(True)
            Select Case cki.Key
                Case ConsoleKey.Enter
                    ' Done
                    Exit While
                Case ConsoleKey.Backspace
                    ' Last char deleted
                    If userInput.Length > 0 Then
                        userInput.Remove(userInput.Length - 1, 1)
                        Console.Write(vbBack & " " & vbBack)
                    End If
                Case Else
                    ' Only append if less than max entered and it's a display character
                    If userInput.Length < maxLength AndAlso Not Char.IsControl(cki.KeyChar) Then
                        userInput.Append(cki.KeyChar)
                        Console.Write(cki.KeyChar)
                    End If
            End Select
        End While
        MsgBox("'" & userInput.ToString() & "'")
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: This is close to what I need, however I need the user to always press enter when it reaches 10 or below and I need them to be able to go back and delete what they have already put using the return. But this is still very useful. Maybe a do while loop might be better for the job.

Comment: I think what I said in my last comment might be very hard to do, its just annoying there is no easy way to limit the length a use can input while still using a readline.

Comment: @Hguin Handling deleting gets more interesting.  The backspace key would be easy enough, so if that's enough, I'll update the answer.  If you want to handle the cursor keys, you'll have to start paying me! :-)

Comment: Thanks very much Mark you have been very helpful :)

Comment: Wow, it works (almost) perfectly! This is amazing, there is only one issue. If i continue pressing down the return till there is nothing left then it crashes. Are you able to fix that?

Comment: @Hguin I've updated the code to handle deleting all the characters - see the `If userInput.Length > 0 Then` check when backspace is pressed.